# How to configure OpenBSD for multiple X Window sessions of different users?

Tags: x11, openbsd, session

I want to configure an OpenBSD (7.2 amd64) system to support multiple users logged in and each having separate X Window sessions, but being able to easily switch whose session is on the terminal.

Usage: This is for a PC I am putting in a shared family area.  I'd like my kids to have separate logins and to be able to leave their programs running without blocking usage by the other kids.  Everyone would use the local display, keyboard, and mouse, but obviously not at the same time.  The key is that one shouldn't need to log out before another can use the system.

A default-installed system allows this for the text console, switching the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F*</kbd>, but it has only one terminal configured for X Windows.  I need at least three separate X Windows sessions.

I tried adding a virtual terminal with `wsconscfg`
and adding a line in `/etc/X11/xenodm/Xervers`,
but only one terminal (the new one) received a xenodm login prompt
and ttyC4 showed a blank screen.

Is this possible?  How do I do it?